# Python: functions in a class and memory

Tags: python, function, memory, instances

If I have a class with several functions:

```
class Example:

    def func1(self):
        print 'Hi1'
    def func2(self):
        print 'Hi2'
    def func3(self):
        print 'Hi3'
```

If I create several instances of 'Example', does each instance store its own copies of the functions in the class? Or does Python have a smart way to store the definition only once and look it up every time an instance uses a function in the class?

Also, what about static functions? Does the class keep only one copy of each static function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference in performance that this would imply.

Comment: im instantiating millions of instances of a class, so I need to understand how the memory is going to be affected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When instantiating a class, no new function objects are created, neither for instance methods nor for static methods.  When accessing an instance method via `obj.func1`, a new wrapper object called a "bound method" is created, which will be only kept as long as needed.  The wrapper object is ligh-weight and contains basically a pointer to the underlying function object and the instance (which is passed as `self` parameter when then function is called).

Note that using `staticmethod` is almost always a mistake in Python.  It owes its existence to a historical mistake.  You usually want a module-level function if you think you need a static method.

Comment: Nicely put and understandable - good note about staticmethod's as well

Comment: Also note that functions objects themselves can (and do) share bytecode, and IIRC only add a bit of metadata (name, module, docstring, captured variables, etc.) atop of that.

Comment: @delnan: That's only true for *local* function, i.e. functions defined inside functions.  The class body is executed only once, and for the functions in the class body, there is a one-to-one correspondence between function objects and code objects.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Really? On Python 3.2 with `def f() { def g(): pass; return g }`, I get true for `f().__code__ is f().__code__`. And I don't see why it wouldn't be the case in 2.x, as code objects have apparently been immutable for a very long time.

Comment: @delnan: I don't see any contradiction between your observation (which is also valid for Python 2.x) and my comment.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Nevermind, I misread. Your comment still doesn't make sense to me. Most of the time, methods and their enclosing classes are only defined once, so *of course* there is nothing to share. However, there is nothing special about function definitions in classes, or class definitions for that matter. You can return local functions for use as a method, and you can put class definitions inside functions so they are executed on every call (a sometimes quite readable alternative to the 3-argument `type`). And because there is nothing special about them, bytecode sharing applies too.

Answer (score 0):

The functions are "stored" in the class, both static and non-static.